# Is using string.length() in loop efficient?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-optimization, loop-invariant

For example, assuming a `string s` is this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++)
```

better than this?:

```
int length = s.length();
for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
```

Comment: The first involves function call overhead once for each iteration of the loop, rather than once only. As far as I know, the `.length()` method _may_ result in a non-trivial calculation (e.g. looping over the string looking for a terminating character), though this is extremely unlikely on any real-world implementation, AFAICT.

Comment: I am not entirely sure (as I am not familiar with the implementation of STL string), however, it seems to me that they would take the same amount of time except `int length` would cost you `sizeof(int)` more memory. This is assuming that `s.length()` simply returns an integer value which is has been stored in the structure.

Comment: @Tim: I think that `.length` is guaranted to be `O(1)`, since `std::string` obeys to the `Sequence` requirements.

Comment: I asked this question because I read on some blog to 'never use s.length() in the conditional in a loop because it has to search through the string to find the NULL terminator each time.' Just wanted to know if that was right.

Comment: @Joel That would be true of `strlen()`, but `string.length()` can't be implemented in the obvious way using a nul terminator since `std::string` allows nul (zero) bytes to be in the string.

Comment: @Matthieu The C++ standard doesn't guarantee that `.length()` has constant complexity; in the container requirements (23.1) it says 'should' rather than 'shall', which allows wiggle room. I don't believe there are in practice any mainstream implementations that have complexity worse than linear, however.

Comment: @Tim: In C++0x n3225 (21.4.4), `size()` is guaranteed to be constant-time and `length()` is defined as *Returns:* `size()` without this guarantee. I don't know if they mean that it is simply an alias or if this allows a higher complexity :/

Comment: @Matthieu I was referring to the 2003 release of the 1998 standard. It's good to know that this has been tightened up in the upcoming standard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, you should avoid function calls in the condition part of a loop, if the result does not change during the iteration.

The canonical form is therefore:

```
for (std::size_t x = 0, length = s.length(); x != length; ++x);
```

Note 3 things here:

- The initialization can initialize more than one variable
- The condition is expressed with `!=` rather than `<`
- I use pre-increment rather than post-increment

(I also changed the type because is a negative length is non-sense and the string interface is defined in term of `std::string::size_type`, which is normally `std::size_t` on most implementations).

Though... I admit that it's not as much for performance than for readability:

- The double initialization means that both `x` and `length` scope is as tight as necessary
- By memoizing the result the reader is not left in the doubt of whether or not the length may vary during iteration
- Using pre-increment is usually better when you do not need to create a temporary with the "old" value

In short: use the best tool for the job at hand :)

Comment: And (4), `length` returns a `size_t`.

Comment: Compilers *often* can optimize away a `.size()` call in the loop, depending on where the `string` or `vector` came from and whether there are any non-inline function calls or `char*` or `T**` dereferences in the loop that the compiler has to assume might alias the control block.

Comment: It's probably best to look at such optimizations as being there for the benefit of those who didn't know better; you should still write your source in a way that makes it easy for the compiler as this answer suggests, as long as you can do that while making it easy for humans to read, too.  But if you don't get a speedup or a change in the asm, it's probably because the compiler was, *in that case*, able to hoist the eval of `.size()` after inlining it.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the inlining and optimization abilities of the compiler. Generally, the second variant will most likely be faster (better: it will be either faster or as fast as the first snippet, but almost never slower).

However, in most cases it doesn't matter, so people tend to prefer the first variant for its shortness.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your C++ implementation / library, the only way to be sure is to benchmark it. However, it's effectively certain that the second version will never be slower than the first, so if you don't modify the string within the loop it's a sensible optimisation to make.

Answer (score 1):

How efficient do you want to be?

If you don't modify the string inside the loop, the compiler will easily see than the size doesn't change. Don't make it any more complicated than you have to!

Answer (score 0):

Is s.length() inline and returns a member variable? then no, otherwise cost of dereferencing and putting stuff in stack, you know all the overheads of function call you will incur for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not necessarily encouraging you to do so, it appears it is faster to constantly call `.length()` than to store it in an `int`, surprisingly (atleast on my computer, keeping in mind that I'm using an MSI gaming laptop with i5 4th gen, but it shouldn't really affect which way is faster).

Test code for constant call:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string g = "01234567890";
    for(unsigned int rep = 0; rep < 25; rep++)
    {
        g += g;
    }//for loop used to double the length 25 times.
    int a = 0;
    //int b = g.length();
    for(unsigned int rep = 0; rep < g.length(); rep++)
    {
        a++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

On average, this ran for 385ms according to Code::Blocks

And here's the code that stores the length in a variable:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string g = "01234567890";
    for(unsigned int rep = 0; rep < 25; rep++)
    {
        g += g;
    }//for loop used to double the length 25 times.
    int a = 0;
    int b = g.length();
    for(unsigned int rep = 0; rep < b; rep++)
    {
        a++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

And this averaged around 420ms.

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but there haven't been any practically tested answers, so I decided to throw my 2 cents in. I had the same question as you, but I didn't find any helpful answers here, so I ran my own experiment.

Comment: Did you forget to enable optimization?  This benchmark allows lots of room for compilers to optimize away much of the work, and your times seem slow.  On i7-6700k Skylake at 4.2GHz on Arch GNU/Linux, I get times more like 115 ms for both with `g++ -O3` (GCC 13.2).  With `rep < g.length()` in the loop, that's slower with clang (16.0 `-O3`): like 125 ms.  And 245M instructions executed (according to `perf stat`) vs. 104M for hoisting it manually.  So your results are backwards vs. mine, but I wouldn't trust this benchmark at all.